# How to get backbone working with forge.request in Trigger.io

Tags: trigger.io, forge

Trigger.io has a forge.request module that takes care of cross-domain HTTP requests.

What's the cleanest way of integrating it into a backbone app?

It is possible to override the Sync method ( for example https://github.com/martindavis/trigger-backbone.sync )

But I don't feel very comfortable using a random plugin for something as important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just following up on my own question. 
I ended up using  https://github.com/martindavis/trigger-backbone.sync with some modifications - so far so good

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this tutorial?

https://trigger.io/docs/current/recipes/javascript_libraries/example_project.html

Comment: link seems to be broken. Their other examples do user forge.request to make ajax calls - that's simple enough. My problem was how to get backbone models to use forge.request seamlessly